# use of "number" word in english

Tags: grammatical-number

which one is  appropriate 
(i) "  6 numbers of student got scholarship in this year"
                      OR
(ii)  "six students got scholarship in this year".

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. I doubt whether your question would suit our English Language Learners site better without some attempt to see which if either variant is used (a Google search would do). Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

First one sounds terribly wrong. The second one is better, but I think would be better as:

"six students got a scholarship this year."

I added the article "a" before scholarship. And I took out the word "in" before this year. If you want you can leave "in" but I personally think it's better without it.